# KUKA LBR iiwa real-time control

Tags: control, ros, kuka, orocos, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to setup the new KUKA LBR iiwa arm for (soft) real-time control (at around 100 Hz for now) in Gazebo and on the actual robot. I was thinking of using ros_control and I'm interested in weather somebody already has a similar setup (HW-interface, URDF/SDF model ...) or is working on it since I couldn't find anything for to the LBR iiwa online.

Thanks and all the best,

-Robert-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198634/kuka-lbr-iiwa-real-time-control/) by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2014-12-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on 2014-12-05**:
Update: I made a URDF description of the arm which can be found [here](https://github.com/rtkg/lbr_iiwa). I am still interested in hints for the control setup though ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Robert,

have you seen this? https://bitbucket.org/khansari/iiwa/src

looks like it is currently used, so I assume it is in a working state: https://bitbucket.org/samirmenon/scl-manips-v2/wiki/iiwa/iiwa_main

---

Originally posted by [marcoesposito1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/7591/marcoesposito1988/) with karma: 191 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on 2015-02-11**:
Thanks, we have a similar solution using the Connectivity Servoing and ros_control right now. One of the issues we have, is that we need velocity control for which there's no interface provided by KUKA. Any input/discussion on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

**Comment by [Hououin Kyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1579/hououin-kyouma/) on 2015-04-21**:
Hi,

I'm currently trying to use the first link, but I get stuck at running the Kuka Hardware Manager. It says "Assignment not possible while KS is running", do you guys have the same problem? If you're using the same thing, that is?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even if there is no open-source ros_control bindings for the LBR iiwa, you can still make good progress on your own. For the Gazebo bindings, try to leverage the existing plugins available in the `gazebo_ros_control` package. For the hardware bindings, you will have to expose to a `hardware_interface::RobotHW` the raw data made available by the manufacturer's API for at least reading state and writing commands. You might also want to handle emergency or protective stops.

**Update:** there is this open-source alternative, just out of the oven: https://github.com/CentroEPiaggio/kuka-lwr

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on 2015-02-11**:
Yes, we're currently working on a hardware interface to connect to the robot which can be found on the repository mentioned above (under heavy development right now though).Thanks for the link, it seems to be for the previous model, the LWR 4 though, not for the new LBR iiwa.

**Comment by [carlosjoserg](https://answers.ros.org/users/4768/carlosjoserg/) on 2015-04-22**:
True, for the LWR 4+. Just to say, we found more useful creating a custom plugin (of course, using the gazebo_ros_control plugin as a template) to add stuff to the sim interface, see our suggested class hierarchy: https://github.com/CentroEPiaggio/kuka-lwr/tree/multi-robot-test/lwr_hw/include/lwr_hw